# Compare string and 0

Tags: vimscript

I just stumbled upon this strange problem:

```
echo 'test' ==# 0
```

This returns `1`. Therefore it is true. But in "reality" it is not true. Any string is different from 0.
How to do this check?

For a bit more context, I actually stumbled upon it with the following code:

```
let l= ['one', 'two', 'three']
let value = get(l, 5)
if value ==# 0
  " do something if the list does not contain index 5
else 
  " do something with the value of the 5th list item
end
```

`get()` returns 0 if the given index is not found in the list. I need to be able to check for this case. But how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design in VimScript strings can be implicitly converted to numbers. Kind of Awk-style. Use `is` operator instead:

```
:echo 'test' is 0
0
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*Matt has good advice for correcting your code. Here's some info on the first part of your question.*

This is actually working as designed:

```
echo 'test' ==# 0
```

This compares 'test' to the number zero before displaying/echoing the result. In Vimscript when you compare a string to a number it gets converted to a number itself. Per `:h variables` (scroll down a bit) unless the string starts with a number it is converted to the number 0.

So the comparison reduces to this:

```
0 ==# 0
```

I.e. `1` (true) and that's what is displayed.

On the other hand, when a string starts with a number it gets converted to that number...

```
echo '3test' ==# 3
```

This also evaluates to and displays `1`.

Yeah, it all may seem a little weird but Vimscript isn't the only language with automatic conversions like this.